# 403 error with Azure Application Gateway and Azure Container App

Tags: azure, containers, gateway

I have followed this official documentation from MS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/waf-app-gateway?tabs=custom-domain

It does not work though. Ikeep receiving a 403 when calling to to the gateway IP address.

Have tried HTTP and HTTPS listeners. Not using WAF just standards gateway. Basically followed that tutorial! Anyone else had a go and got it working?

The health probe to the backend pool container app shows success as I have a simeple GET /WeatherForcast shows a 200 success. Got a 403 when accessing the application gateway IP via HTTP or when I setup a hostname using HTTPS.

Comment: FIXED!
If anyone else seems to get the problem look at the Hostname override.
Use "Override with specific domain name" Enter the FQDN of your container app.

Comment: Post your solution as an answer to get it highlighted with the community who face the same type of issues.